# How to understand the 'Flexible schema' in Cassandra？

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra, and found below in the wikipedia.

**A column family (called "table" since CQL 3) resembles a table in an RDBMS (Relational Database Management System). Column families contain rows and columns. Each row is uniquely identified by a row key. Each row has multiple columns, each of which has a name, value, and a timestamp. Unlike a table in an RDBMS, different rows in the same column family do not have to share the same set of columns, and a column may be added to one or multiple rows at any time.[29]**

It said that 'different rows in the same column family do not have to share the same set of columns', but how to implement it? I have almost read all the documents in the offical site.

I can create table and insert data like below.

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_record(E_id int PRIMARY KEY,E_score int,E_name text,E_city text);
INSERT INTO Emp_record(E_id, E_score, E_name, E_city) values (101, 85, 'ashish', 'Noida');
INSERT INTO Emp_record(E_id, E_score, E_name, E_city) values (102, 90, 'ankur', 'meerut');
```

It's very like I did in the relational database. So how to create multiply rows with different columns?

I also found the offical document mentioned 'Flexible schema', how to understand it here?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Column family is from the original design of Cassandra, when the data model looked like the Google BigTable or Apache HBase, and Thrift protocol was used for communication. But this required that schema was defined inside the application, and that makes access to data from many applications more problematic, as you need to update the schema inside all of them...

The `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` is a part of the Cassandra Query Language (CQL) that was introduced long time ago, and replaced Thrift-based implementation (Cassandra 4.0 completely removed the Thrift support). In CQL you need to have schema defined for a table, where you need to provide column name & type.  If you really need to have dynamic columns, there are several approaches to that (I'll link answers that I already wrote over the time, so there won't duplicates):

1. If you have values of the same type, you can use one column as a name of the attribute/column, and another to store the value, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968338/cassandra-data-modeling-when-columns-are-dynamic/60970294#60970294)
2. if you have values of different types, you can also use one column as a name of attribute/column, and define multiple columns for values - one for each of the data types: `int`, `text`, ..., and you insert value into the corresponding columns only (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203270/cassandra-dynamic-column-family/60204948#60204948))
3. you can use maps (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596982/how-to-handle-dynamic-columns-in-cassandra/60599463#60599463)) - it's similar to first or second, but mostly designed for very small number of "dynamic columns", plus have other limitations, like, you need to read the full map to fetch one value, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not know if I implement different rows with different columns?

Comment: Cassandra requires that only primary key should be specified during insertion - all other columns are optional - if you don't specify value, you'll get `null` back. So you can just do, `insert into table (pk1, pk2, col1) values (1, 2, 3)` then `insert into table (pk1, pk2, col3) values (2, 3, 5)`, and you'll get 2 rows - in first you'll have only value in `col1`, and in second - only in `col2`